# Retrieve factor with labels/levels as colname with maximum value. Problem with dropped level

Tags: r, string, vector

Ii just got a predict of a multinomial logistic model, which gives the probabilities of my classes (columns) from my data.

I got something like this.

[image]

The problem is that I have created a function to retrieve the name of the column with the max value, store it in a vector and factor it with labels with the same name as my columns. BUT, because I don't obtain any value as the fifth column, it doesn't work.

```
max_name_col <- function(df, vec =c(1:5)) {

  
  etiq = colnames(df[,vec])
  return (factor((colnames(df[,vec])[apply(df[,vec],1,which.max)]), labels=etiq))
}
```

And if I don't use it and try to factor it by itself, the levels change and since I lost the third column (Every prob of this is really really low), so I cannot compare it with the original class. (Since my 4th class is indeed the 5th in the original data).

**How could I alter my function so it works despise there is no max_value in my column that "drops"?**

Answer (score -1):

Ok, i solved it. Just add the levels so they concord with the names of the columns.

```
max_name_col <- function(df, vec =c(1:5)) {


  etiq = colnames(df[,vec])
  return (factor((colnames(df[,vec])[apply(df[,vec],1,which.max)]), levels=etiq, labels=etiq))
}
```